# Why do I get 'Access to undeclared static property? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate some data. I found this [tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/laravel-form-validation) at scotch.io. I'm using the following in my UsersController to attempt to validate some data:

```
public function store(){

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

        return Redirect::action("UserController@index");

    }
```

However, I keep getting the error 'Access to undeclared static property: User::$rules'. Am I doing something wrong? I've attempted to use 'php artisan dump-autoload'

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $fillable = array(
                          'username',
                          'forename',
                          'surname',
                          'email',
                          'telephone',
                          'password',
                          'admin',
                          'customer',
                          'verification_link'
                        ); 


    public static $rules = array(
        'name'             => 'required',                       // just a normal required validation
        'email'            => 'required|email|unique:ducks',    // required and must be unique in the ducks table
        'password'         => 'required',
        'password_confirm' => 'required|same:password'          // required and has to match the password field
    );

}
```

Comment: Honestly, everything looks good. Try running `php artisan dump-autoload` again. Maybe you accidentally ran it in a different folder (happened to me before..). Or try to make the variable an object, instead of static.

Comment: Tried your code, no errors showing up. Probably you can move the rules into the controller, since it's the controller responsible for validating, not the model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find a solution for me online, and I traced the problem with PHPStorm, and found out that my Class was defined "TWICE" and so it was reading the first one rather than the one I wanted which is the second one.

The problem you probably have is that your migration files include a migration file for the "User" table, and which defines its class as `Class User extends Migration {` and the definition of the `Class User` in your Model will go like `Class User extends Eloquent` and so the solution is to change one of them to either:

`Class CreateUser extends Migration` or `Class UserModel extends Eloquent`

and then use the Model's method according to your change, so you either keep it

`User::$rules` or `UserModel::$rules` and that's only if you've changed your Model Class name.